# Apache mod_rewrite erratically duplicates arguments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have mod_rewrite working on an Apache2. The rewrite condition causing the problem is

```
RewriteRule ^(blog|press|library)(.?)$ /?p=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

which rewrites the URL as expected for blog and press, i.e.

```
www.example.com/blog
```

is internally redirected to

```
www.example.com/?p=blog
```

So far, so good. But for the URL

```
www.example.com/library
```

we suddenly get

```
www.example.com/library/?p=library
```

in the address bar of the browser, and have in the mod_rewrite log file:

```
[...] rewrite 'library/' -> '/?p=library'
[...] split uri=/?p=library -> uri=/, args=p=library&p=library
```

where the split should only result in args=p=library

The QSA directive is required because I need an URL like `/library?book=xyz` to work.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Do you have a directory called "library"?

Comment: Yep, exactly, this was causing the behavior, thanks Jon!